# AWS Cognito User Pools and OpenId

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, amazon-cognito

I am playing around with Amazon Cognito and after reading some of the docs and creating a user pool I am running into some issues. I believe that a cognito user pool can be used with OpenId to redirect the user to a hosted UI for user authentication (without federating out to another provider). I have tried to use the authentication options in DotNetCore 2 to do this as this is something I have done previous with other providers.

I have the following:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    options.ResponseType = "code";
    options.MetadataAddress = $"https://cognito-idp.{authOptions.AwsRegion}.amazonaws.com/{authOptions.PoolId}/.well-known/openid-configuration";
    options.ClientId = authOptions.ClientId;
    options.ClientSecret = authOptions.ClientSecret;
});
```

but everytime I try it always returns

```
{"code":"BadRequest","message":"The server did not understand the operation that was requested.","type":"client"}
```

Just wondering if anyone had any experience with this please? I have tried to create the user pool in different regions just to make sure that it is not only supported in certain regions but always get the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used to have the same problem. Configured my pool and code according to [this](https://dzone.com/articles/identity-as-a-service-idaas-aws-cognito-and-aspnet) tutorial. The crucial part was

> Another configuration that may be important is the App integration > Domain name. It allows us to configure what will be the domain of the sign-in and sign-up pages.

After I configured domian name everything worked fine.